# Android App crash each time Strings separated by .split is used in query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, separator

My App crashes each time I use strings separated using split as variable for my DB query. My DB File contains multiple table. I've tried multiple trials to determine which part of my code has an error and found out that it was from my strings separated. I cant find any other way how to separate my strings.

```
    public void setString(String str){
       //string from MainTranslator received from MCU(using Arduino)
       //which was Serial.print("LETTERS,191,124,136,210,205,9,0,0,1,5,-2");
        theString = str;
    }

    public String getResChar(){
        //split strings with commas
         String toSeparate = theString;
         String[] separated = toSeparate.split(",");

         TBName = separated[0];
         FlxThumb = separated[1];
         FlxIndex = separated[2];
         FlxMiddle = separated[3];
         FlxRing = separated[4];
         FlxPinky = separated[5];
         AcX = separated[6];
         AcY = separated[7];
         AcZ = separated[8];
         GyX = separated[9];
         GyY = separated[10];
         GyZ = separated[11];
         query= "SELECT GESTURE FROM " + TBName +
            " WHERE FLXTHUMB = " + FlxThumb +
            " AND FLXINDEX = " + FlxIndex +
            " AND FLXMIDDLE = " + FlxMiddle +
            " AND FLXRING = " + FlxRing +
            " AND FLXPINKY =" + FlxPinky +
            " AND ACX = " + AcX +
            " AND ACY = " + AcY +
            " AND ACZ = " + AcZ +
            " AND GYX = " + GyX +
            " AND GYY = " + GyY +
            " AND GYZ = " + GyZ;
         Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

         String CharacterResult = null;
         if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
             cursor.moveToFirst();
             do{
                CharacterResult = cursor.getString(0);
             }while(cursor.moveToNext());
         }
         cursor.close();
         return CharacterResult;
      }
```

Comment: You better post logs of exceptions from logcat. Plus use defensive programming for data validity checks (null, properly formatted, etc)

Comment: can you share logcat.